# How to fetch the key of an array that contains a specific substring?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:-

```
$ header_menu = array(
    ['category'] => array(
                    'id'    => 1,
                    'title' => 'Test Apple',
                    'slug'  => 'category'
                    ),
    ['how-to-do'] => array(
                    'id'    => 1,
                    'title' => 'How to do',
                    'slug'  => 'how-to-do'
                    )               
)
```

The array is formed dynamically based on the data saved in the table. Due to that, sometimes the key can be `'category'`, sometimes it can be `'categories'`, based on what the admin has saved in the DB.

I need to fetch the key which has the substring `'categor'`, because this sequence of alphabets is present both in `'category'` & `'categories'`. By the following code, I can check if the `'categor'` substring is present in any of the key or not:-

```
if (preg_grep('/^categor/', array_keys($header_menu)))
{

}
```

One way is to run a loop like this:-

```
foreach($header_menu as $key => $row)
{
   if(strpos($key, 'categor') !== false)
   {
       $catKey = $key;
   } 
}
```

However, I don't want to run a loop. Is there any other way to fetch the matching key?

Comment: And again - what's the problem with loop? You cannot iterate over array without loop. Almost all array functions iterate over provided array(s).

Comment: No matter what ever function will help you for this, but internally it will apply loop only.

Comment: Also if you know that keys can be either `category` or `categories` then just check with `isset/empty`

Comment: @u_mulder, Some idiot clients open the source code and try to pretend "know-all". Those idiots have issue with loop (ie something that they can identify as loop).

Comment: implode all the keys with a delimiter of your liking, then use your regular expression magic. there no loop. and why on earth is the problem using a `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you have only **two** options `category/categories` , you can check if one of this fields exists in array:

```
if (isset($header_menu['category'])) {
    $key = 'category';
} elseif (isset($header_menu['categories'])) {
    $key = 'categories';
}
```

`switch` variation which allows many options:

```
switch (true) {
    case isset($header_menu['category']):
        $key = 'category';
        break;

    case isset($header_menu['categories']):
        $key = 'categories';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_grep if you do not want to loop through with [array_keys()](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_keys.php) to get every key of your array and find all key matching given pattern.

```
$matchingKeys = array_keys($header_menu);
$matchingKeys = preg_grep('/'.'categor'.'\.\d/i', $matchingKeys);
```

Comment: i think `preg_grep()` on array will use loop internally